# Google Maps Link Name

Tags: usability, terminology, hyperlinks, google

We have an application that provides an address to a commercial property. There's a use case in which users will need to view the property in google maps. I was wondering if there's a standard link name or method for adding the link?

**Option 1: Make the address a hyperlink**

I would be concerned that the user doesn't know what they hyperlink means or where they would be going if the click it

**Option 2: Add a hyperlink below the address**

I think this is  probably most intuititive but I'm not sure what the properly label the hyperlink so a user understands. Is simple saying "Google Maps" enough or does it need to be more explicit, e.g., "View Property in Google Maps"?

0000 Main Street

Mingo, CA 12345

[Google Maps](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a hyperlink divert the user from your app. Better embed the google map on your app instead of adding hyperlink.

**Or**

If you only want to add a hyperlink, then add a text saying **Locate our property on Google Map** and upon clicking that link it should open PopUp to show your google map.

Answer (score 2):

Your concerns with making the entire address a hyperlink are valid. Another potential issue with that approach is that it would make trying to copy the address more difficult, as users might inadvertently launch the link while just trying to copy the address.

Option 2 makes much more sense, and you could be even more concise with a link of, “View in Google Maps”. In the context, the user should know what it is they will be viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Having a reference map (small static map to show the property and its surrounding) is ideal. If that's not possible then having a button labeled 'Show on map' is second best; in my opinion you can scratch 'Google', people don't give a flip which mapping technology is used.